# Meshlabserver : Cannot connect to X server error

Tags: php, ubuntu-14.04, xserver, meshlab

I have meshlab installed in my machine running Ubuntu 14.04 OS. I can access it from command line using `meshlabserver` command. But problem arises whenever I try to call it from a php script using the command

```
<?php
system('meshlabserver 2>&1');
?>
```

It shows the error `meshlabserver: cannot connect to X server`. After going through a few websites I did the following things:

I moved the `meshlabserver` executable from `/usr/bin` to `/usr/local/bin` and gave it executable permissions using

```
sudo chmod a+x meshlabserver
```

But when I ran the `whoami` command from my php script (calling the `meshlabserver`), it showed `www-data`. So I gave executable permissions for all users to the `meshlabserver` using

```
sudo chmod 777 /usr/local/bin/meshlabserver
```

But still it is showing the same `meshlabserver: cannot connect to X server` error. `meshlabserver` comamnd is working fine when ran from the command line.

I really need to call `meshlab` from the php script for my website. Thus any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the php script can't access your display variable. If you logged in via ssh remember to tunnel your X-server via 'ssh -X ...' Your second option is to create a virtual frame buffer using Xvfb and redirect the display variable to it:

`export DISPLAY=:100.0
Xvfb :100 &`

Note the ampersand for the second command as Xvfb needs to be running in the background.

Comment: It didn't work. However I found an alternative command to perform the task and need not invoke Meshlabserver any longer. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Unfortunately, `meshlab` requires an OpenGL context, which `Xvfb` apparently cannot supply. Consequently, the second option does not work.

Answer (score 0):

a combo of prior answers works for me:
`ssh -X`, as well as `export DISPLAY=:0.0` (on remote)